# Removing add new in a custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, visual-web-part

I am currently using Sharepoint 2013 foundation. I created a custom Web Part in Visual Studio to help filter a custom list on logged in users. Each logged in user will see a separate view. I then add the custom web part to a page, and it works great.

The only issue is it keeps the '+ new item' option and it adds a light gray border around the web part.

Would it be possible to add code to the custom web part to remove the '+ add new' and to remove the gray border.

Below is the c# for my custom web part:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System.Collections;

namespace Custom_Webparts.Stab_List_Summary
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class Stab_List_Summary : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing         Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission     attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
    // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
    // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    public DCS_Stab_List_Summary()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sitename")) // This URL needs to be changed to appropriate URL. 
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                // refer to the Stab List
                SPList olist = web.Lists["Stab List"]; // "Stab List" needs to be changed to appropriate list name

                //new XSLT webpart
                XsltListViewWebPart webpart = new XsltListViewWebPart();

                //custom XSLT Listview webpart properties
                webpart.ListName = olist.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
                webpart.AllowEdit = true;
                webpart.AllowConnect = true;
                webpart.AllowZoneChange = true;

                //Refer views for different user
                SPView oTView = olist.Views["Summary T"];
                SPView oEView = olist.Views["Summary E"];
                SPView oNormalView = olist.Views["Summary"];

                //getthe logged in user name
                SPUser oUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;


                //If logged in user is T_sp, then apply appropriate view
                if (oUser.Name.Contains("T_sp")) // t_sp
                {
                    webpart.ViewGuid = oTView.ID.ToString("B");
                }
                else if (oUser.Name.Contains("E_sp")) // e_sp;
                {
                    webpart.ViewGuid = oEView.ID.ToString("B");
                }
                // for other supply default view
                else
                {
                    webpart.ViewGuid = oNormalView.ID.ToString("B");
                }

                this.Controls.Add(webpart);
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is a link to show an image of the gray border I am speaking about: 
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `XsltListViewWebPart` internal controls and hide the Toolbar control like:

```
//Find the ToolBar control and set visible to False 
foreach (Control ctrl in webpart.Controls) 
{ 
  if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ViewToolBar)) 
  { 
    ctrl.Visible = false; 
    break; 
  } 
}
```

Or you can use Reflection to set the Toolbar to none for View, as shown in
 [SharePoint: Programatically add XSLTList view webpart to page](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/08/programatically-add-xsltlist-view.html)

However which Grey border are you referring to? Can you add a snapshot

Comment: I will try the code you put above and let you know the results. So basically, I paste the code you provided right below my code that says //new XSLT webpartXsltListVewWebPart webpart = new XsltListViewWebPart();    ? I have edited my original post to show the image of the gray border.

Comment: Sorry, this is new to me. When I paste your coding into the XsltListViewWebPart section, it tells me that "The name '_wpListView' does not exist in the current context". Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: @CalebFortner the `_wpListView` should be replaced with your XsltListViewWebPart object i.e. `webpart`

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but like I said, this is all new to me. So I currently have 'XsltListViewWebPart webpart = new XsltListViewWebPart();', then you gave me 'foreach (Control ctrl in webpart.Controls) 
{ 
  if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ViewToolBar)) 
  { 
    ctrl.Visible = false; 
    break; 
  } 
}'. What should my new code look like?